# jquery how to replace live text?

Tags: json, replace

i've got some text that is being loaded into a `<span>` from a json file.

the json file has some fields that come as `null` and i would like to replace them with something else.

i've een trying this :

```
var e = $('span.black').text();
e.replace(/\null/g, "test");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Another thing is that i try to replace the text immediately after i load the json file.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you change the text right after the JSON is loaded like this:

```
if (!data.someKey) {
   data.someKey = "some default text";
}

$('span.black').text(data.someKey);
```

or, if you really need to replace the value after it was added to the span:

```
var elem = $('span.black');
elem.text(elem.text().replace(/null/g, "some default text"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML:

```
<span id="target">Old Content</span>
```

The following JQuery code will change the content:

```
$('#target').html("New Content");
```

[Example @ jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/nmsqq/1/)